# VBA Trim one Object with another Object in string (FSO.Getfolder related) Basically end up with relative path to a file

Tags: excel, vba, trim, subdirectory, fso

I am building this index of files in a directory.
Column 1 with folder name(s), Column 2 with filename

I have managed to get the actual filename and hyperlinking the filename already.
But I have problems listing the path to the file in column 1, using a relative path including its subfolders.

Say I have the following folder:
"C:\users\ME\Documents"
Inside that folder there are many subfolders.

What I want to achieve is a string that list the path to that actual subfolder.
Example:

```
"C:\users\ME\Documents\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\CharlieSheen.pdf"
Column 1 (A5) = Subfolder1\Subfolder2\
Column 2 (B5) = CharlieSheen.pdf
```

As I said I have control over column 2.

The script I am using already is

```
Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal strpath As String, _
ByVal intRow As Integer, ByRef objFSO As Object) As Integer
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer`
i = intRow - ROW_FIRST + 1

Set objFolder = objFSO.Getfolder(strpath)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'print file path
    Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFolder.Name

i = i + 1
    Next objFile
    GetAllFiles = i + ROW_FIRST - 1
End Function
```

I figured out that changing
    `Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFolder.Name`

into `Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFSO.Getfolder(".")` returned exactly what I wanted to remove from the first string!

So I basically want to write a script that says:

`Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFolder.Name - objFSO.Getfolder(".")`

But I need help since that command obviously doesn't work.

There might be a totally different approach to this, but since my macro already have a lot of code, using Trim or Replace or similar would be the easiest?

**Edit:**
There's also a function in my script named "GetAllFolders".
Maybe I can call on that in some way to implement the string I want?

```
Private Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, _
    ByRef objFSO As Object, ByRef intRow As Integer)
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object

'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
'loops through each file in the directory and
'prints their names and path
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    intRow = GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, _
        intRow, objFSO)
    'recursive call to to itsself
    Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, _
        objFSO, intRow)
Next objSubFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(i+ROW_FIRST -1, 1)  = Replace(objFolder.Name, objFSO.GetFolder("."), "")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Similar to Macro Man's suggestion this solution returned only "Subfolder2". Not "Subfolder1\Subfolder2".
Do you have any idea why? The script I copied also has a function for "GetAllFolders" and use a recursive approach.
Will it help if I update my question to include this?

Comment: If you just need to remove the "C:\Users\username" from the path, you could just replace it instead with `Cells(i+ROW_FIRST -1, 1) = Replace(objFolder.Name, "C:\Users\ME\Documents", "")` or if it needed to work for all users, then something like `Replace("C:\Users\ME\Documents\Somefile.pdf", CStr(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%")), "")`

Comment: I might have been a bit quick when I explained.
objFSO.GetFolder(".") returns "C:\user\ME\". And objFolder.Name returns "Subfolder2". I am sorry to say that my own suggested replacement naturally don't work when I have no command that inserts the whole path

Comment: I fixed it! Instead of using objFolder.Name, I had to use objFolder.Path, and then apply your great replacement solution! Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = Replace$(objFolder.Name, CStr(objFSO.Getfolder(".")), vbNullString)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried adding your solution as both a substitute for my original line, and in addition to (under) my original line.
In both cases only "Subfolder2" gets printed in the cell.
It doesn't print as "Subfolder1\Subfolder2". Any idea why?